Validation of string in list of string via regex in data annotation
I have a class Detail with a parameter of type List<string>
public class Detail
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [RegularExpressionList("^[a-zA-Z0-9א-ת@/\\.\\- !@#$%&*()_+]*$")]
    public List<string> parameters { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

public class RegularExpressionListAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute{
public RegularExpressionListAttribute(string pattern)
    : base(pattern) { }

public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if (value is not IEnumerable<string>)
        return false;

    foreach (var val in value as IEnumerable<string>)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(val, Pattern))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

And I create with swagger JSON schema of from the Object from type Detail.
Now I need to add a limitation to string with regular expression with the use in data annotations, so I added regular expression but it setting in JSON schema of swagger only for array not for the string:
  "Detail": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "index": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9א-ת@/\\.\\- !@#$%&*()_+]*$",
        "maxItems": 50,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "nullable": true
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }

How can I do it without setting the list to a list of objects and the regular expression be display in SWAGGER's schema?

Did you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-8.0

"I added regular expression but it setting in JSON schema only for array not for the string:" If you are not handwriting the OpenAPI Spec here you should tell us with what you generate it. And then tag the question with that properly. "Swashbuckle" or "NSwag" for example.
